# The result of macro has to be the value of the last expression in the body

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, label

I have this macro which is a "for" loop and it works great.

```
(defmacro for ((parameter start-value end-value
                         &optional (step 1))
                        &body e)
           (let ((func-name (gensym))
                 (step-name (gensym))
                 (end (gensym)))
             `(labels ((,func-name (,parameter ,end ,step-name)
                         (when (<= ,parameter ,end) 
                           ,@e 
                           (,func-name (+ ,parameter ,step-name)
                                       ,end
                                       ,step-name))))
                (,func-name ,start-value ,end-value ,step))))
```

But i need the result of my macro to be the value of the last expression in the body (of the body). Right now (in this code) the result is always `nil`. So what do i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example for a single return value:

```
CL-USER 38 > (defmacro for ((parameter start-value end-value
                             &optional (step 1))
                            &body e)
               (let ((func-name (gensym))
                     (step-name (gensym))
                     (end       (gensym))
                     (last-name (gensym)))
                 `(labels ((,func-name (,parameter ,end ,step-name ,last-name)
                             (if (<= ,parameter ,end)
                                 (,func-name (+ ,parameter ,step-name)
                                             ,end
                                             ,step-name
                                             (progn ,@e))
                               ,last-name)))
                    (,func-name ,start-value ,end-value ,step nil))))
FOR

CL-USER 39 > (let ((j 0) (k 1))
               (for (i 1 10 (incf k))
                 (print i)))

1 
3 
5 
7 
9 
9           ; the return value
```

Comment: If the body takes more than one expression `(progn ,@e)` is needed.

Comment: it wont work for this kinda test: `(for (new-el 1 5) (print (+ new-el 2) (print (- new-el 2))))`

Comment: @AntonKaravaev: the parentheses in your code are wrong. When fixed, it returns 3, which looks fine to me...